# Can shared memory be inconsistent between OpenMP parallel regions?

Tags: c++11, concurrency, openmp

I'm writing a tool to test some graph algorithms. The tool has to go through all the edges in the graph and mark nodes at either end under certain conditions. It then has to go through all the nodes, ensuring they were all marked. The code should be pretty straight-forward, but I'm having some concurrency issues.

Here is my code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:seen_edges) default(shared)
for (size_t i = 0; i < n_edges; i++)
{
    int64_t v0 = node_left(edges[i]), v1 = node_right(edges[i]);

    // Do some work...

    // This is where I mark nodes if the other end of the edge corresponds to the parent array
    if (v0 != v1)
    {
        if(parents[v0] == v1)
            reached[v0] = true;
        if(parents[v1] == v0)
            reached[v1] = true;
    }

    // Do more work...   
}

#pragma omp parallel for default(shared)
for (size_t i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++)
{
    if (i != source && !reached[i])
        error("No traversed edge leading to node", i, &n_errors);
}
```

The reached array is initialised to `false` everywhere.

I can guarantee that on the input I'm using all the nodes should be marked, and thus no error should be printed. However, *sometimes*, some nodes remain unmarked.

I think memory shared should be consistent between OpenMP parallel regions, and I never set any element in `reached` to false except for at initialisation. The implicit barrier at the end of the first region should prevent any thread from going into the second one until all edges have been checked (and all nodes marked on this test input).

I see two possible options, but have no further explanation:

1. Some kind of data race is going on. But because I never set elements back to false, even if multiple threads try to write to a location at the same time, should that element eventually become `true`?
2. The elements are set to `true`, but memory is not consistent between threads in the second parallel region. Can this even happen in OpenMP?

If someone has any insight, I'd be grateful. Cheers.

Edit: The `// Do work` parts don't use the `reached` array, and `parents` is never modified in the program.

Comment: Most likely, the race condition is somewhere in the `// Do more work...` parts.

Comment: The commented parts don't touch the `reached` array in any way, and `parents` is not modified anywhere in the program. I will edit my question to add this info.

Comment: The shared data must be updated and the updates visible to all threads after a barrier or a join/fork. You have some other problem. Maybe it would be worth using a race detection tool such as Intel Parallel Inspector? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Parallel_Inspector

Comment: @Andrei Is your graph one in which there are no closed loops? As is, it seems to me that two separate threads can set their `v0` or `v1` the same as another thread and then change the `reached` array, creating this inconsistency. To answer your titular question though: No it cannot be inconsistent.

Comment: I'm not claiming that `reached` is touched inside `// Do more work...`. I rather claim that there is something that prevents the `if` conditions from being true, therefore it prevents `reached[...]` from being set to `true`. And I second Jim Cownie - run your program through a thread-checker tool.